# How to identify the words with same pronunciation?

Tags: differences

How to identify or differentiate the words with same pronunciation.

As saying with example,

1. speak with mic.
2. speak with mike.

So my question is when you hear these two words, How you can identify that they mean the mic(sound system) or mike(person).

Comment: You wouldn't speak "with" Mike (the person). Rather you would speak "to" Mike.

Comment: @itsols speaking with someone (about something) is quite normal.

Comment: You would speak with **a** mic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You identify the correct meaning from context. [Homophones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homophone) exist in all natural languages, not just English. In your mother tongue, too. If you have enough context, you can tell which meaning is intended. If you don't have enough context, it's ambiguous.